# Send email notification to node author with Rules

Tags: 8, rules

I am trying to notify the node author of a new comment on their node.

Using Drupal 8.3

Created new reaction rule.

Send to:  comment.entity_id.entity.uid.entity.mail.value

email address is not being picked up

I get this email from system:

A message that you sent contained no recipient addresses, and therefore no
delivery could be attempted.

Comment: have you tried debugging by inspecting the token values incrementally?  In other words- render/log comment.entity_id.entity.uid to see if you get the actual user id of the author?  

If you navigate to /admin/help/token , you'll get a full list of tokens, and should be able to test/debug the values to see the desired result that populates your send to field.

Comment: based on this legacy thread for D7, https://www.drupal.org/node/1362258; I think the token should be something like:

**comment:entity:entity:author:mail**

Comment: Hi Anson, I tried debugging it and don't get an email.  But according to this https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/201079/send-email-notification-with-rules it should have worked.

Comment: I don't see the token you mention. Can only get comment:entity. Then it doesn't expand anymore.

Comment: Not sure if this is right [comment:author:original:mail]

Answer (score 1):

This worked.

As a workaround, you can use the data selection string as a token in the direct input textarea.

Switch to data selection and get your string, in my case content_moderation_state.uid.entity.mail.value

Switch to the direct input mode and paste the string with double braces {{content_moderation_state.uid.entity.mail.value}} to use the token replacement API.

As described here: https://www.drupal.org/project/rules/issues/2799569#comment-12376804