# How to send email verification link with webform?

Tags: 8, webforms

I am using a webform for anonymous users (logging in is not an option). Once a webform is submitted, I want to send out an email asking to click on a confirmation link. Only once this link is clicked, I want to take further actions (i.e. trigger an email handler or change the status of the webform).

How can I achieve this or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

Afaik this is not yet implemented in webform. Not sure, if it will at all. There is a module in dev that tries to solve the issue, but it requires some effort to make it work: [Email Confirmer](https://www.drupal.org/project/email_confirmer).

Another option is to build this with the Rules module. Here's something similar for inspiration: [Send email notification when a new comment is posted](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/201079/send-email-notification-when-a-new-comment-is-posted)